# Adding one dictionary to another based on values (python 3)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
yod_user = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\yod_user.xlsx")    
yod_bank = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\yod_bank.xlsx")

#converting DataFrames into dictionary
userd = yod_user.to_dict()
bankd = yod_bank.to_dict()

#Definitions
userd =  [{"id":2, "username":"pk@gmail.in","password":"YkxJNWNDT"},
         {"id":4, "username":"test@gmail.com", "password":"VjNUYWh"},
         {"id":6, "username":"zz113@gmail.com", "password":"dddd"},
         {"id":8, "username":"faulmike@aol.com", "password":"ssss"},
         {"id":10, "username":"newr10@gmail.com", "password":"errfs"}]

bankd = [{"userid":"2" "bankid": "99" "acc_number": "4590" "bank_name":"xyz"},
{"userid":"4" "bankid": "100" "acc_number": "4520" "bank_name": "abc"},
{"userid":"6" "bankid": "56" "acc_number": "4980" "bank_name": "xyz"},
{"userid":"8" "bankid": "99" "acc_number": "4570" "bank_name": "ypr"},
{"userid":"2" "bankid": "17" "acc_number": "4530" "bank_name": "abc"}]
```

What i want to achieve from the above code is something like this:

```
 Result
 [{"id": 2, "username":"pk@gmail.in","password":"YkxJNWNDT"
"account": 
 {"userid":"2" "bankid": "99" "acc_number": "4590" "bank_name": "xyz"},
  {"userid":"2" "bankid": "17" "acc_number": "4530" "bank_name": "abc"}
 ]
```

Basically, all the information about one id should be in one key. So, the key is the **"id"** from **'userd'** and for that id all the information i.e. the username etc. and the bank details should be there. All the accounts held by id = 2 should come together. How can I achieve this?

To embed the "bankd" in "userd" with reference to id.

Once I achieve this, I can convert it into json and store in mongodb which is the main target. Any help appreciated..

Comment: Fix your data, please, you cannot declare key value pairs inside lists.

Comment: Please try and understand the problem. The code can be fixed later. I am new to python so maybe the syntax is not right but I hope the problem is clear.

Comment: cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is making a reasonable request.  It's just as important for you to take the time to post a thoughtful, well-written question, as it is for answers to be clear and insightful.  It's inappropriate to expect people to struggle through your poor formatting to find a way to help you.  Make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: I did edit it. But as I said I am new to python. And yeah, I agree with you in everything. Just excuse me for this. Thank you

Comment: @andrew_reece is right. Once you updated your post, I was able to quickly use your data to formulate a solution. You'd have received help even faster had you done so from the start. Remember, you asked for help, not me. You could stand to put in that much amount of effort.

Comment: Ok I will certainly take care of the next time. The answer has a lot of things about which I have no clue. What has happened to df2. Where can I read about it?

Comment: Nothing happened to `df2`. Also, if you want me to see your questions, please comment under my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df1   # yod_user

   id   password          username
0   2  YkxJNWNDT       pk@gmail.in
1   4    VjNUYWh    test@gmail.com
2   6       dddd   zz113@gmail.com
3   8       ssss  faulmike@aol.com
4  10      errfs  newr10@gmail.com

df2   # yod_bank

  acc_number bank_name bankid userid
0       4590       xyz     99      2
1       4520       abc    100      4
2       4980       xyz     56      6
3       4570       ypr     99      8
4       4530       abc     17      2
```

First, take `df2` and convert it to a list of dictionaries grouped by `userid`:

```
df3 = df2.set_index('userid', drop=False)\
         .rename_axis('id')\
         .apply(dict, 1)\
         .groupby(level=0)\
         .apply(lambda x: x.tolist())\  # x.values.T.tolist()
         .to_frame('account')

df3.index = df3.index.astype(int)

df3

                                              account
id                                                   
2   [{'bankid': '99', 'userid': '2', 'bank_name': ...
4   [{'bankid': '100', 'userid': '4', 'bank_name':...
6   [{'bankid': '56', 'userid': '6', 'bank_name': ...
8   [{'bankid': '99', 'userid': '8', 'bank_name': ...
```

Note here that I converted the `df3.index` to an integer type, since `df1.id` is of integer type as well. This will help with the next step.

Now, perform a `merge`:

```
df = df1.merge(df3, left_on='id', right_index=True)

df

   id   password          username  \
0   2  YkxJNWNDT       pk@gmail.in   
1   4    VjNUYWh    test@gmail.com   
2   6       dddd   zz113@gmail.com   
3   8       ssss  faulmike@aol.com   

                                             account  
0  [{'bankid': '99', 'userid': '2', 'bank_name': ...  
1  [{'bankid': '100', 'userid': '4', 'bank_name':...  
2  [{'bankid': '56', 'userid': '6', 'bank_name': ...  
3  [{'bankid': '99', 'userid': '8', 'bank_name': ...
```

(Optional) convert to records:

```
import pprint    
pprint.pprint(df.to_dict('r'))

[{'id': 2,
  'password': 'YkxJNWNDT',
  'userid': [{'acc_number': '4590',
              'bank_name': 'xyz',
              'bankid': '99',
              'userid': '2'},
             {'acc_number': '4530',
              'bank_name': 'abc',
              'bankid': '17',
              'userid': '2'}],
  'username': 'pk@gmail.in'},
 {'id': 4,
  'password': 'VjNUYWh',
  'userid': [{'acc_number': '4520',
              'bank_name': 'abc',
              'bankid': '100',
              'userid': '4'}],
  'username': 'test@gmail.com'},
 {'id': 6,
  'password': 'dddd',
  'userid': [{'acc_number': '4980',
              'bank_name': 'xyz',
              'bankid': '56',
              'userid': '6'}],
  'username': 'zz113@gmail.com'},
 {'id': 8,
  'password': 'ssss',
  'userid': [{'acc_number': '4570',
              'bank_name': 'ypr',
              'bankid': '99',
              'userid': '8'}],
  'username': 'faulmike@aol.com'}]
```

Comment: Please guide as where can I find a good resource to learn python.

Comment: @KaranGupta This is a great link and I think you'll find a lot of useful info if you follow it: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F And for pandas, look at the 10-minute tutorial: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Comment: I got an error: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'` while converting df2 to list

Comment: @KaranGupta `tolist` doesn't work on dataframes, only series. Use `df2.values.tolist()` instead, if you need to.

Comment: What is df2 in your solution? Is it not a DataFrame?

Comment: @KaranGupta It is a dataframe.

Comment: ` .apply(lambda x: x.yod_bank.values.tolist())` says: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'yod_bank'`

Comment: `.apply(lambda x: x.values.T.tolist())`. This converted the df into a list. Please update the answer if you find it correct.

Comment: @KaranGupta This code worked for the sample data in my Q... it's quite possible that adapting it to your code/data would yield different results... best to keep them separate.

Comment: Ok, what your code does in the specific part is convert the df3 values to a list that's it right? For me `.apply(lambda x: x.values.T.tolist())` this works, so it won't make any difference right.

Comment: @KaranGupta Maybe it also depends on your pandas version. I'm on 0.21.

Comment: `pd.__version__

'0.20.1'`. I am working on it. If anything else comes up, I'll post it here ok.

Comment: @KaranGupta Surprising... my answer works for this data, very strange :-) I edited the answer in case anyone else has problems.

Comment: Another issue is that the end part `import pprint    
pprint.pprint(df.to_dict('r'))` does not give me the desired output. I am losing the keys as in acc_number, bankid etc. and only getting the values which are useless.

Comment: @KaranGupta I'm really surprised that you are running the same code on the same data and getting different results.

Comment: The data is different. I posted dummy data here. But everything else is same. I am getting everything as desired, just losing the attribute name. Maybe if we convert the "account" into a dictionary rather than a list it will work?

Comment: @KaranGupta Try this? `df.to_dict('i')`

Comment: I am posting a new question to make it more clear ok.

Answer (score 0):

The simple, inelegant approach is to use a nested for-loop, and match on `id`/`userid`:

```
for u_entry in userd:
    u_entry["account"] = []
    for b_entry in bankd:
        if b_entry["userid"] == str(u_entry["id"]):
            u_entry["account"].append(b_entry)
```

Output:

```
[{'account': [{'acc_number': '4590',
    'bank_name': 'xyz',
    'bankid': '99',
    'userid': '2'},
   {'acc_number': '4530', 'bank_name': 'abc', 'bankid': '17', 'userid': '2'}],
  'id': 2,
  'password': 'YkxJNWNDT',
  'username': 'pk@gmail.in'},
 {'account': [{'acc_number': '4520',
    'bank_name': 'abc',
    'bankid': '100',
    'userid': '4'}],
  'id': 4,
  'password': 'VjNUYWh',
  'username': 'test@gmail.com'},
 {'account': [{'acc_number': '4980',
    'bank_name': 'xyz',
    'bankid': '56',
    'userid': '6'}],
  'id': 6,
  'password': 'dddd',
  'username': 'zz113@gmail.com'},
 {'account': [{'acc_number': '4570',
    'bank_name': 'ypr',
    'bankid': '99',
    'userid': '8'}],
  'id': 8,
  'password': 'ssss',
  'username': 'faulmike@aol.com'},
 {'account': [],
  'id': 10,
  'password': 'errfs',
  'username': 'newr10@gmail.com'}]
```

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 0):

it would be easier for you to keep your data as pandas dataframes (i.e. perform your operations on `yod_user, yod_bank`). Regardless, using your variable names:

```
userd =  pd.DataFrame([
    {"id":2, "username":"pk@gmail.in","password":"YkxJNWNDT"},
    {"id":4, "username":"test@gmail.com", "password":"VjNUYWh"},
    {"id":6, "username":"zz113@gmail.com", "password":"dddd"},
    {"id":8, "username":"faulmike@aol.com", "password":"ssss"},
    {"id":10, "username":"newr10@gmail.com", "password":"errfs"}
])

bankd = pd.DataFrame([
    {"userid":"2", "bankid": "99", "acc_number": "4590", "bank_name":"xyz"},
    {"userid":"4", "bankid": "100", "acc_number": "4520", "bank_name": "abc"},
    {"userid":"6", "bankid": "56", "acc_number": "4980", "bank_name": "xyz"},
    {"userid":"8", "bankid": "99", "acc_number": "4570" ,"bank_name": "ypr"},
    {"userid":"2", "bankid": "17", "acc_number": "4530", "bank_name": "abc"}
])

# Your data was not in the same format between bankd and userd. 
bankd['userid'] = pd.to_numeric(bankd['userid'])

# Iterate through the dict and append results from searching through dataframes
def append_bankd(df_in):
    userid = df_in['id']
    df_in['bankd'] = bankd[bankd['userid']==userid].to_dict('r')
    return df_in
result = [append_bankd(m) for m in userd.to_dict('r')]

# Sample result
[
    {
        'bankd': [
            {'acc_number': '4590',
            'bank_name': 'xyz',
            'bankid': '99',
            'userid': 2},
   {
        'acc_number': '4530', 'bank_name': 'abc', 'bankid': '17', 'userid': 2}],
        'id': 2,
        'password': 'YkxJNWNDT',
        'username': 'pk@gmail.in'}, ...
]
```